# Typescript AST: how to distinguish `extends` and `in` clauses in a TypeParameterDeclaration node

Tags: typescript, parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I am parsing a typescript source file using a library that provides the typescript Abstract Syntax Tree as processed by the typescript compiler.

In order to verify the correctness I am rebuilding the entire string source file from the AST. This should provide a sufficient test that I am interpreting correctly the AST nodes.

Most of the work is done but I found an apparent ambiguity. The TypeParameterDeclaration node is returned from the parser for both `extends` and `in` clauses.

Case 1: `extends` clause

```
 type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

 "K extends keyof T" is a TypeParameterDeclaration node with 2 children:
   - "K" is an [Identifier node]
   - "keyOf" is a [TypeOperator node] with 1 child:
      - [TypeReference node] with a child:
         - "T" [Identifier node]
```

Case 2: `in` clause

```
 export type LayoutAnimationTypes = {
      [type in LayoutAnimationType]: type;
  };

 "[type in LayoutAnimationType]" is a TypeParameterDeclaration with 2 children:
   - "type" is an [Identifier node]
   - [TypeReference node] with one child:
      - "LayoutAnimationType" is an [Identifier node]
```

In both cases the two nodes apparently do not contain anything suggesting which of the two clauses should be used to "rebuild" the string.

**Question**: how can I know whether the TypeParameterDeclaration specifies a "in" or "extends" clause?

---

### Adding more info

The two ASTs can be compared with this online viewer:

- https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AHgCoBooGkoQB7AQB2AJgM5QDWEIA9gGZSoB8UAvFAAoIDGlamAKJ4eAGwCuJCMmp1GGbM2YBuIA
- https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAyBDRECuMCCAdgJYC2GMxEhAKssAM5wC8cA3gFBzfcDaSKOMULosuAiXKVqdFAF0AXAnoBuLgF81QA

Basically this just testify there are no info in the AST to determine the two clauses.
Anyway, it is significant that `getText()` reports the correct clause.
Its implementation just gets the **substring** from the original parsed source text:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/compiler/utilities.ts#L524

The `getText()` functions shows that the **AST is missing an important information** and implies there is no way to build an AST from its nodes and then convering it to text.

Is this really true?

Comment: Which library are you using to parse the code?

Comment: I am currently using two different C# libraries from a C# console. 
Their authors both claims to have ported the typescript AST library from the typescript compiler.
Even if from different authors, the libraries have exactly the same structure (due to the porting). In fact I can recompile the code by just changing the reference and the usings directives.

Comment: I added more context with the online AST viewer and the link to the typescript compiler source file that shows how the "extends" / "in" clasuses are only obtained through a substring. This is a disaster when manually crafting the AST and then converting to text since there would be no parsed source file.